# opencv-declare a mat of vectors

Tags: c++, opencv

I need a Mat object where each element is a vector with type double and size 15.

I tried

```
Mat seq(rownum,colnum,Vec<double,15>);
```

But this gives me the error:

> expected primary expression before ')' token

How do I specify this typename?

Answer (score 1):

Rupesh and Paul, I will try what both of you said, but meanwhile my fiddling led me to the following solution.

```
Mat seq(rownum,colnum,CV_64FC(15));
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `Vec<double,15>` is a type, then you need to construct it:

```
Mat seq(rownum,colnum,Vec<double,15>());
```

Answer (score 0):

if it is vector then Syntax should be

```
Mat seq(rownum,colnum,Vec<double>(15));
```